How to filter Splunk table rows using inputlookup values
I have 2 inputlookups and I want to output a table with fields from lookup1
but only rows where columnA matches a value from lookup2. For example:
Lookup 1:
| inputlookup lookup1 | search status=6 | fields servicename, status, app_version, release_type
servicename1, 6, 12.1, Production
servicename2, 6, 14.0, Demo
servicename3, 6, 14.4, Testing

Lookup 2:
| inputlookup lookup2 | fields servicename, hostname
servicename2, server34,companyy.com
servicename5, server12,companyy.com

I was trying something like this:
| inputlookup lookup1 | search status=6 |
| eval check = if(match(servicename, IN (|inputlookup lookup2 |fields servicename)),1,0) 
| search check=1
| table servicename app_version release_type 

Hoping to get results like:
servicename2, 14.0, Demo 


But the match operator doesn't seem to support an IN() parameter so not sure what else to try.

I figured out a solution using join and a subsearch. e.g.:
| inputlookup lookup1  | join left=L right=R where L.servicename =
R.servicename  [ inputlookup lookup2 ]  | fields L.servicename,
R.app_version, R.release_type

